Groovy: How to display the values starting only with numbers?
I am trying to display the output starting only with the numbers using groovy.
My script:
def successfulBuilds = [QA-228-7443c745-Final_QA_Signed-Off, 227-7443c569-Final_QA_Signed-Off, QA-226-5ca5659c-QA_Signed_Off, 225-137b4c34-QA_Signed_Off, 224-40d92670-QA_Signed_Off, QA-223-c212132c-Fail_the_Jenkins_pipeline, QA-222-20367839-Merge_branch__master__into_POC-Pipeline-Ownership-SRE, 221-20343339-Merge_branch__master__into_POC-Pipeline-Ownership-SRE]

I am expecting the o/p like below:
[227-7443c569-Final_QA_Signed-Off, 225-137b4c34-QA_Signed_Off, 224-40d92670-QA_Signed_Off, 221-20343339-Merge_branch__master__into_POC-Pipeline-Ownership-SRE]
What modifications should I make to get the above o/p.
Thanks
Pritish

I don't know enough about the Jenkins build model to know if there is other information you can use but if you know that it is definitely the names starting with numbers that you want, I would change your findAll line to be something like:
def successfulBuilds = nums.findAll { it.result == hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS && it.displayName[0] in '0'..'9' }*.displayName


Just FYI, I have updated my query. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I was able to resolve like below:
def successfulBuilds = [QA-228-7443c745-Final_QA_Signed-Off, 227-7443c569-Final_QA_Signed-Off, QA-226-5ca5659c-QA_Signed_Off, 225-137b4c34-QA_Signed_Off, 224-40d92670-QA_Signed_Off, QA-223-c212132c-Fail_the_Jenkins_pipeline, QA-222-20367839-Merge_branch__master__into_POC-Pipeline-Ownership-SRE, 221-20343339-Merge_branch__master__into_POC-Pipeline-Ownership-SRE]
def filterSuccessfulBuilds = successfulBuilds.findAll { it =~ /^\d+-/ }
echo "${filterSuccessfulBuilds}"

